# Given an analytic function can I derive to what precision I need to evaluate its arguments to get a result of a given precision?

Tags: real-numbers, machine-precision, truncation-error

Suppose I have some arbitrary analytic function over the reals e.g.:

$$ x \mapsto \frac{\sqrt{\sin(x)+2e^x}}{x^2 - \ln(x^x)} $$

Given some input of arbitrary precision $x$ how can I evaluate such an expression to a given precision such that the first $n$ bits are correct.

For example consider $ a + b $, to evaluate this expression to *n* bits I need only evaluate $ a $ and $ b $ to $ n $ bits.

However for multiplication to evaluate to $ n $ bits I need to evaluate $ a $ and $ b $ to a higher precision to avoid precision loss in the result.

In general given an analytic function (e.g. $ x \mapsto \sqrt{x}) $ can I determine what precision I need to evaluate its arguments in order to get $ n $ bits in the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, no level of precision will ensure that the first $n$ bits are correct.  For example, if the value of the expression happens to be exactly $2$ (but you don't know that), a numerical evaluation may well give you something slightly less than $2$, and then even the first bit will be wrong.

What you **might** be able to do is to guarantee that the absolute error will be at most a given number $\epsilon$.